# how to convert duplicate values as unique in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

suppose if i found duplicates can i make those as unique value something like this ?(For first duplicate occurrence should add '-1',second duplicate occurrence )

> - VF12R071659666728
> - VF12R071659666728
> - VF12R071659666730
> - VF12R071659666731
> - VF12R071659666731
> - VF12R071659666731

should be like this

> - VF12R071659666728-1
> - VF12R071659666728-2
> - VF12R071659666730
> - VF12R071659666731-1
> - VF12R071659666731-2
> - VF12R071659666731-3

this just example. i have to check these on 25000 records don't know which is unique and which is duplicate!!  is there any way please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula will work:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,$A1)=1,$A1,$A1&"-"&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1))
```

Example:

[image]